# how to switch to another optimizer in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to change optimizer in the middle of training. 
I use the code from this post: 
[Changing optimizer in keras during training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47626254/changing-optimizer-in-keras-during-training)

as follows:

```
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv12)

def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
    return backend.sqrt(backend.mean(backend.square(y_pred - y_true)))#, axis=-1))

class OptimizerChanger(EarlyStopping):

    def __init__(self, on_train_end, **kwargs):
        self.do_on_train_end = on_train_end
        super(OptimizerChanger, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        super(OptimizerChanger, self).on_train_end(self, logs)
        self.do_on_train_end()

def do_after_training():
    model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae', rmse])
    model.fit(x_train_n, y_train_n, batch_size=10, epochs=200, validation_split=0.05, shuffle=True)

changer = OptimizerChanger(on_train_end= do_after_training,
                       monitor='val_rmse',
                       min_delta=5,
                       patience=10)

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
          optimizer='adam', 
          metrics=['mae', rmse])

history = model.fit(x_train_n, y_train_n, batch_size=10, epochs=200, validation_split=0.05, shuffle=True, callbacks=[changer])
```

I get the following error:

```
super(OptimizerChanger, self).on_train_end(self, logs)
TypeError: on_train_end() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

what is the third parameter that is being passed? is it implicit? how do I call it?

Comment: Hint, it's easier to use a `LambdaCallback(on_train_end = do_after_training)`. Where in this case it should be `def do_after_training(logs):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the method from an instance and you are passing `self` to it. So it's redundant.

```
super(OptimizerChanger, self).on_train_end(self, logs)
```

This line should be

```
super(OptimizerChanger, self).on_train_end(logs)
```